# How can I edit txt to xls in Unix?

Tags: csv, text-formatting

I want to convert my txt file to xls/csv.

The first row should print datetime and second row should print the remaining all data (from tid to table in below example)

When m using the below command

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t"; print "DateTime,Error"}; NR > 1{print $1,$2;}' TMP.txt > Output.xls
```

Its printing datetime in first row but only printing tid in next column.

Can anyone please help me to print the whole remaining text in second column

Record in text file:

```
2019-11-26T11:51:32.087-08:00 tid: JCA-work-instance:AQ Adapter-8 userId: <anonymous> 0 , APP: Service Bus Logging FlowId: 0000MtDbHiu8pmk5Szd9ic1TlVox0015xl RouteNode2, null, null, REQUEST Queried data from header table
```

The following types of log entries should also be considered:

```
Nov 28, 2019 8:19:03 AM PST HTTP BEA-101019 [ServletContext[text] Servlet failed with an IOException. 
Nov 28, 2019 8:22:40 AM PST [null, null, null, ERROR] error in service-callouterror service to get information
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the behaviour you see is that per default, `awk` treats `WHITESPACE` (i.e. space, tab) as input field separator. Thus, *every* item in your input file that is surrounded by space is treated as a single "field" and is assigned its own `$<number>` internal variable. Your `awk` command, however, instructs  `awk` to print only the first two such fields (`$1` and `$2`), which are in your case the date/time string and the literal `tid:`.

In your particular case, the easiest way might be to use `sed` to replace the *first* white-space by a tabulator, which should give the desired result.

Since you also want to include a header line, the following should work (assuming GNU `sed` is being used):

```
sed -e '1 i\DateTime\tError' -e 's/ /\t/' TMP.txt > Output.txt
```

The first expression inserts one line of text at the beginning of the line, the second performs the "actual formatting" intended.

**Update**

For the additional string format you provided, I would resort to `awk` instead of `sed` (note that I use GNU awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf("DateTime\tError\n")} {match($0,"^([[:alpha:]]{3}[[:space:]]+[0123]?[[:digit:]],[[:space:]]+20[[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]+[01]?[[:digit:]]:[012345][[:digit:]]:[012345][[:digit:]][[:space:]]+[AP]M[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]+([[:print:]]*)$", fields); printf("%s\t%s\n", fields[1], fields[2])}' TMP.txt > Output.txt
```

This regular expression matches a time format as specified by you, followed by one or more space, followed by arbitrary printable characters up to the end of the line, and prints the first `(...)` sub-group, the timestamp, then a `\t`, and then the second `(...)` sub-group, which is "the rest of the line". Additionally, the `BEGIN` anchor is used to insert the header line on top.

Since both cases can occur in the same file, we have to combine them into a single `awk` program:

```
BEGIN {
    printf("DateTime\tError\n");
}

{
if (match($0,"^([[:alpha:]]{3}[[:space:]]+[0123]?[[:digit:]],[[:space:]]+20[[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]+[012]?[[:digit:]](:[012345][[:digit:]]){2}[[:space:]]+[AP]M[[:space:]]+[[:upper:]]+)[[:space:]]+([[:print:]]*)$", fields) == 0)
    match($0,"^(20[[:digit:]]{2}-[01][[:digit:]]-[0123][[:digit:]][[:alpha:]][012][[:digit:]](:[012345][[:digit:]]){2}.[[:digit:]]{3}[+-][012][[:digit:]]:[012345][[:digit:]])[[:space:]]+([[:print:]]*)$", fields);

printf("%s\t%s\n", fields[1], fields[3]);
}
```

You can call the above script `xlsconvert.awk` and then call it as

```
user@host$ awk -f xlsconvert.awk TMP.txt > Output.txt
```

Note that this will, of course, keep the different timestamp formats in the output. If you want to convert that to a unified format, you may have to resort to a shell script.

Comment: Hi @Adminbee, Thanks for the update. The same is working fine for this date format. When the date format is getting changed. like Nov 28, 2019  8:08:41 AM PST am using this command and its working fine  sed -e '1 i\DateTime\tError' -e 's/     /\t/' TMPCluase.log > Output.log
The command is working fine if my string starts with [null....... but its not working when its starts with HTTPS

Comment: Details of string is below

Comment: Nov 28, 2019  8:19:03 AM PST  HTTP BEA-101019 [ServletContext[text] Servlet failed with an IOException.
Nov 28, 2019  8:22:40 AM PST     [null, null, null, ERROR] error in service-callouterror service to get information

Comment: I see. Please edit the question to merge the example content you just provided, (it's easier to read that way).

Comment: Also, please ensure to provide examples of _all_ timestamp formats we may encounter; depending on the possible variations, a different approach may be needed.

Comment: Sure. thanks anyways :)

Comment: It just occurred to me: do we encounter all these different timestamp styles found in _the same_ `TMP.txt`, or are we speaking of different files there?

Comment: Its in same TMP.txt